# How to get all the tab elements listed in android.widget.TextView using appium?

Tags: appium

I want to click all the tab elements listed in TextView which is inside HorizontalScrollView. There are 13 tabs but following code fails to get the actual count, Any suggestion or alternative method to find tab elements?

```
List <WebElement> tablist = driver1.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.TextView\").resourceId(\"net.abc.xyz:id/txt_tab\")");

int n = tablist.size();
System.out.println("Number of tabs " +n);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    tablist.get(i).click();
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tries using findElements by xpath?

First locate the HorizontalScrollView element and search for the TextView elements in the scroll view.

So your code will be something like this.

```
Webelement scrollView = driver.finElement(By.xpath("scroll view locator here"))
scrollView.finElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@resourceId='net.abc.xyz:id/txt_tab']"))
```